# How to get all substrings (contiguous subsequences) of my JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

My task is to split the given array into smaller arrays using JavaScript. For example `[1, 2, 3, 4]` should be split to `[1] [1, 2] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4] [2] [2, 3] [2, 3, 4] [3] [3, 4] [4]`.

I am using this code:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  let a = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    a.push(arr[j]);
    if (a.length === i) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(a);
}
```

And I get the following result: `[1] [1, 2] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4] undefined`

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should set j=i in begin loop

Comment: @AlexandrKudryashov I have tried. It is not correct

Comment: set j=i and remove the if condition in the nested loop

Comment: init i with 0 and remove the = symbol in the corresponding condition

Comment: Please if you suggest something, try it yourself first and see if it actually works.

Comment: @rockstar nope, it is not correct

Comment: For actually trying to do your own homework before posting here, have +1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. You need to have loop to initialize with the value of `i` for the inner loop so that it consider the next index for new iteration of `i`
2. You need to remove that `break` on the length which you have in inner loop.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  let a = [];
  for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
    a.push(arr[j]);
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this code is logging the *same* array `a` to the console on successive iterations of the inner loop, and modifying it in between. Admittedly, this is what the OP's code does, too, but it's likely to surprise anyone who tries to naively modify this code e.g. to collect all the subsequences in a single array and return it. [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363453) provides a more easily generalizable solution using `.slice()`.

Comment: Outer loop should use `<` instead of `<=`. It currently does an extra iteration only to be broken on the next line where you check `j < arr.length`.

Answer (score 16):

For the inner array, you could just start with the index of the outer array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    i, j, l = array.length,
    result = [];
    
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < l; j++) {
        result.push(array.slice(i, j + 1));
    }
}
console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This do one big array. Target is to create small arrays

Comment: what do you want with small arrays? instead of pushing, you could display the sub array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
 let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
       for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
          let a = [];
          for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            a.push(arr[j]);    
              console.log(a);            
          }  
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need the `tmp` variable?

Comment: you can do it without tmp variable=)

Answer (score 0):

Use two iteration

1. get slice array based on loop index.
2. use sliced array and combine array element.

```js
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let newArra =[];
  arr.map((x,i)=> {
       let remainArr = arr.slice(i);
       return remainArr.forEach((y, r) => newArra.push(remainArr.slice(0, r+1)))
  })
  newArra.forEach(x=> console.log(x))
```

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks, Made the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

i have prepare [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8htiwj) for this case.

```
let source = [1,2,3,4];
const output = [];
const arrayMultiplier = (source) => {
  const eachValueArray = [];
  source.forEach((item, index) => {
    // Will push new array who will be sliced source array.
    eachValueArray.push(source.slice(0, source.length - index));
  });
  //We reverse array to have right order.
  return eachValueArray.reverse();
};

for(let i = 0; i <= source.length; i++) {
  output.push(...arrayMultiplier(source));
  source.shift();  // Will recraft source array by removing first index.
}
//Don't forget last item.
output.push(source);
console.log(output);
```

Is not the most shorten solution but do the job

== update after code review ==

```
// [...]
const arrayMultiplier = (source) => {
    // Will push new array who will be sliced source array.
    // We reverse array to have right order.
  return source.map((item, index) => source.slice(0, source.length - index)).reverse();
};
// [...]
```

Comment: Avoid `forEach` + `push`, use `map` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate your array.

```
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
      let a = [];
      for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
        a = [...a, arr[j]];
        res = [...res, a];
      }
    }
 console.log(res);
```